# ICS file to open in gmail through button C#

Tags: c#, .net, calendar

I am trying to generate an ICS file which is coming as an attachment to my email. I want to add a button to that email which, when clicked takes us to gmail (may be ask username for gmail where we need to add the event) and add it to the gmail calendar. I m not able to find anything of this sort. Can anyone help

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
    sb.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
    sb.AppendLine("PRODID:Domain.com");
    sb.AppendLine("CALSCALE:GREGORIAN");
    sb.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
    sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
    sb.AppendLine("UID:" + guid);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", retailStore.LocationEmail));
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN='{0}, {1}';ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=TENTATIVE:MAILTO:{2}", CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, CustomerEmail));
    sb.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + DateStart.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
    sb.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + now);
    sb.AppendLine("SUMMARY: " + Summary);
    sb.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + Location);
    sb.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:" + Description);
    sb.AppendLine("PRIORITY:5");
    sb.AppendLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE");
    sb.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
    sb.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

    var calendarBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(calendarBytes);
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, FileName, "text/calendar");
    customerMailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the message recipient is using Gmail, they will see an option to add the event when the ICS file is correctly created in their inbox.

[image: ICS view in gmail inbox]

Other email clients may (but not always) support this as well, but the experience for the recipient may vary, and the event may be saved in a calendar other than Google, depending on the user's configuration.

If you want to include a button to create the event in Google Calendar, you can generate a link like this:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=MyEvent&details=Description&location=London&dates=20230719T205300Z%2F20230720T205300Z&add=you@example.com
```

Parameters:

- text: event name
- details: event description
- location: event location
- dates: start and end date in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (separated by the `%2F` character [`/` in [HTML encoding]](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP))
- add: email address of the event guest

All parameters are optional, and the user will have to confirm the event themselves. They will be the organizer and can remove you, change all settings, etc.

Remember, this link is not in any way related to the ICS file you are creating!

Comment: Can you share the api documentation link if any

Comment: @EmaanAliKhan https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/main/services/google.md

Comment: and how can we update the already added event/ or delete it